# building my own gcc version

Tags: gcc, dynamic-linking, gfortran, gcc4.7

My distro (CentOS 6.3) comes with gcc 4.4.6. Since I wanted to try out the Fortran2003 features I decided to compile gcc 4.7.

I followed the steps I found online: compiled separately first gmp, mpc, mpfr, ppl and cloog and the compiled gcc.

I run the configured script as:

```
configure --prefix=... --with-gmp=... --with-mpfr=... --with-mpc=... --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-ppl=... --with-cloog=... --disable-multilib
```

This worked all right and I was able to compile with `make` & `make install`.

Now, when trying my new compiler with a simple test program (a hello world kind of thing) I get the error:

```
gfortran-4.7 -o test test.F90

/home/amcastro/gcc-4.7/output/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.0/f951: error while loading shared libraries: libcloog-isl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I decide to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/amcastro/gcc-4.7/output/lib`
and then I can compile.

When running I get the error:

```
./test

./test: error while loading shared libraries: libquadmath.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/amcastro/gcc-4.7/output/lib:/home/amcastro/gcc-4.7/output/lib64`

and now the program runs normally.

The question is: Why is that my distro version of gcc (4.4.6) does not need me to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? how does the distro gcc know where to look for these dynamically liked libraries? should I somehow make them to link statically?
I read also that setting `LD_LIBRARY_FLAG` is not a good idea. Is there another solution?

Thank you in advance

A.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `read that setting LD_LIBRARY_FLAG is not a good idea`?

Comment: @devnull, I read about this in the following links:  [http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html]  [http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html]  Besides, my main concern is why I should set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or compile like with the -rpath option if I do not need to do this with the distro compiler. Why?

Comment: Chances are that they are cached by [ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig); The directories in `/etc/ld.so.conf` are already known to the linker-loader. Prepending things like: `$HOME/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the correct approach. Leave `ld.so.conf` for 'trusted' system / distro libraries.

Comment: @BrettHale , could you expand on this? I looked into /etc/ld.so.conf and It has the one line include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf.  I also looked into the files withing ld.so.conf.d and neither of them seem to point libcloog or libquadmath.

Comment: When building things like gcc, it's typical for the system search paths for headers and libraries to be hard-coded into the build. Have a look at `gcc -v` to see the options your system compiler was built with.

Comment: @BrettHale  It does give me the options used in the configure. However nothing regarding library paths.

Comment: when you built mpg, mpfr, mpc, isl, cloog etc, did you provide the `--disable-shared` config option?  Doing that will mean the shared libs are not built, and therefore, when you later build gcc, it will have to link to the static libraries, and then you won't have the missing library problem at runtime.